# Office 365 Read-only mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, read-only

Is there anyway to make the Office 365 Site Collection as `Read-only` mode?

Please help me by providing your valuable reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not supported in SharePoint Online (http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/223877.aspx).

I would suggest you remove the permission of users by adding them into Reader Groups.

Or temporarily change group permission to Read Only.

Comment: This is not a good approach because, if for some reason we want to revert the users back to their original groups then we should know which user belongs to which group. Is there any way like site policy to apply in `Modern Team Sites`???

Answer (score 4):

you can lock a site using the Powershell or CSOM approach. Their is one command([Set-SPOSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx)) in SharePoint Online which set the lockstatus to the site collection.

> Sets the lock state on a site. Valid values are: **NoAccess** and **Unlock**.
>   When the lock state of a site is **NoAccess**, all traffic to the site
>   will be blocked. If parameter **NoAccessRedirectUrl** in the **Set-SPOTenant**
>   cmdlet is set, traffic to sites that have a lock state **NoAccess** will
>   be redirected to that URL. If parameter **NoAccessRedirectUrl** is not
>   set, a 403 error will be returned.

PowerShell:

```
Set-SPOSite https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/targetsite -LockState [NoAccess|Unlock]
```

**CSOM**
To do this in CSOM, you can utilize the TenantAdministration API; however, this is only available in the v16 SharePoint Online API.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(tenantUrl)) {
    clientContext.Credentials = spoCredentials;
    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
    var siteProperties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteUrl, true);
    clientContext.Load(siteProperties);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("LockState: {0}", siteProperties.LockState);

    siteProperties.LockState = "Unlock";
    siteProperties.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

When the site is locked, you'll see it in the admin site with a lock icon next to it as seen below.

[image]

Source: [How to change the lock state via CSOM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sumanc/archive/2014/11/19/how-to-change-the-lock-state-via-csom.aspx)

Comment: This will not make it READ ONLY. It will basically block all access.

Comment: yes, that is what i mention in the anwser that, you have only two values Noaccess and Unlock....

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP I believe the code that you shared uses specific userid/password. Is this possible with App Only Permissions?(<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />)

Answer (score 4):

To set a SharePoint online site into read only mode use the site policy feature. Create a policy with the configuration showed: 
[image]

Switch to site closure and deletion option within the site settings and close the site with the read only policy

[image]

You should see a warning text panel at the top of the site

Answer (score 1):

Seems like MS implemented "ReadOnly" option for SPO.
Although it is not documented yet.
But I just was able to do powershell 
"`Set-SPOSite $site -LockState Readonly`".
And get

```
PS C:\Users\Vlad> $site | select Title, Status, LockState | fl
Title : test01
Status : Active
LockState : ReadOnly
```

and well-known red "This site is read only at the farm administrator's request." [image: Read-Only for SPO]

Comment: This does work.   PNP PowerShell Also supports the LockState switch.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpsite

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Vladilen's answer works with SharePoint online now, and with the SharePoint portion attached to an O365 group (file store as well as site).

I would have replied to his answer but I just created this account and don't have a high enough reputation yet to comment or upvote.