# How to make a SP2013 subsite (not site collection) read-only?

Tags: sharepoint-server, read-only

Is there any way to make a SP2013 subsite (not site collection) read-only? I know you can make a site collection read-only using site policies but how can one make a subsite Read-Only without altering the permission levels on the sites?

This thread indicates there's possibly a Lockstate for SPO
[Office 365 Read-only mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140636/office-365-read-only-mode/275329#275329)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like SP expert said, there is no way to move a sub-site to read-only mode. Remove permissions from all users in the Sub site will be a way to try.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality available at subsite site level, locking available only at site collection level.

What you can do as a workaround,

- Go to to Sub-site permission setting from Site settings
- Stop the inheritance
- Remove all users /groups or change their permission level. If you
  want to restrict for short time then make sure you copy the
  permission somewhere else before.

Reference URL :

[Powershell Script to temporarily disable SharePoint subsite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236418/powershell-script-to-temporarily-disable-sharepoint-subsite/236429#236429)